# CMS Error 518 while sending messages using AT Commands

Tags: gsm, modem, at-command

I have connected a gsm modem to my computer. I am trying to read sms from gsm modem and send sms to other mobile numbers using AT commands. When I type

> at+cmgl ="all"

It lists all the messages from SIM card. But the messages displyed in hyper terminal are like this..

+CMGL: 1,"REC READ","004C004D002D00560065006E005300650063",,"11/12/15,16:10:04+2
2"
0041007400200063006C006F00730065002C002000530065006E0073006500780020003100350038
003300360028002D003400350029002C0020004E0069006600740079002000340037003400360028
002D0031003700290020006C006500640020006200790020006D006500740061006C007300200028
0053007400650072006C006900740065002D00340025002900200026002000630061007000200067
006F006F0064007300200028004200480045004C002D003300250029002E0020004500750072006F
007000650061006E0020006D006B00740073002000740072006100640069006E0067002B00760065
002E00200044006F00770020006600750074002B0037002E002000560045004E0054005500520041

+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","00540041002D0049004E004E005300450054",,"12/03/24,20:32:04+2
2"
00480069002100200059006F00750072002000640065007600690063006500200073007500700070
006F0072007400730020004D004D0053002C005400410054004100200044006F0063006F006D006F
0020004400690076006500200049006E00200061006E006400200047005000520053002E00530061
0076006500200066007200650065002000730065007400740069006E0067007300200079006F0075
0020006100720065002000610062006F0075007400200074006F0020007200650063006500690076
006500200061006E006400200065006E006A006F00790020006F00750072002000560061006C0075
0065002000410064006400650064002000730065007200760069006300650073

While the messages in sim cad are in simple text format. How can I see the messages from sim card in text format in Hyper terminal?

Also when I try to send the message from hyper terminal using command

> at+cmgs="phone number"

It gives me error saying

> +CMS ERROR: 518

Can Anybody tell me what's the problem?

Note: I have set sms service centre no.

Comment: Have you set the operating mode to text? (by sending AT+CMGF=1) That might be why you are not seeing the real text for the CMGL command.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your message format is not set to Text format and is likely in PDU mode. You should give `AT+CMGF=1` to set to text format.

Also you are getting `+CMS ERROR: 518` means that your **storage type is invalid**. Set your storage appropriately